# How to migrate ( ETL ) 500 million rows of data from schema A to schema B where schema B is different/updated and contains FK?

Tags: mysql, database-migration, etl, load-data-infile

I have a project where schema A, basically schema version 1.0, has been refactored and updated in a new schema B, version 2.0 on a complete code refactor. Schema A has no FKs and has some data as comma separated lists, xml text, etc. Schema B stores the same data as column and relations to FK in some instances, and is normalized. How would one migrate/translate 500 million, and ever increasing, rows efficiently? I've tried scripting by gathering the data via selects, manually relating the data, and then inserting it as it should, but it's very slow.

Comment: My current approach is to dump the data into CSV files, load it into HDFS, run some PIG scripts to filter, etc , and then create files to import via LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Why not doing it through a software? any language you want, select data, transform it and insert. without CSV files or these manually tools.

Comment: With that amount of data and the severity of the schema design changes you implied, I don't think there is really a "fast" way. If you want to do it incrementally, you could always log the key of the last row (or modify schemaA tables to have an `exported` flag field) successfully migrated so that the process knows where to resume next execution. Also, what did you mean by "manually relating the data". You might want to include a example of the kind of code you are using for this...

Comment: @Uueerdo "manually relating data" means the legacy system does a lot of data relationships in the code and mixes of other db columns. An example would be a table X with a text field containing xml data like   `<data><item id="1">a</item><item id="2">b</item>`. Then another table Y with a column that references the item like `||id || itemId || ... || `` where itemId would be 1 or 2 . In the new schema the xml in the text field is a table and table Y in new schema would be an FK to that new tables id

Comment: @Uueerdo another example would be in old schema A a text colum in table X is a comma separated list like `54,102,104,55,50,924,105,65,930,57` where the values are ids in tables Y. and in the new schema B that list is a join table X_Y

Comment: @PatrickHMcJury I get the idea now, I was just confused by your wording specifying it separate from the inserting; it made me wonder if you were perhaps doing something in data structures before moving it to the new schema.

Comment: @Uueerdo no problem. My question is basically trying to ask for a solution other than the way you described or an ETL like job. The schema is so radically different in some cases that it's almost like a get the source data, transform it, filter it, etc and then load it. It's easy for the smaller tables, but for the larger ones it's very time consuming and can only be accomplished in a reasonable time window via load data infile. Thanks for the help